# Trying to loop values into curl command from a file

Tags: curl, for

I am not even sure if this is possible or not. I am trying to create a loop where i can curl with different values from a file.

```
for i in `cat id`;
do curl -X POST 'https:/myurl \
--header 'X-XX-Authorization: XX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'ACS-Licensing-Ack: XXXX' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'XXID=`find * -name $i`'
done
```

I get a response

```
{"code":"400-bad-request","message":"XX app with ID `find * -name $i` not found"}
```

How do i put in the value from $i that i captured earlier into this --data-urlencode field?
My id file is very simple, it contains a few numbers like below.
1234
23232
32323
any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

This is my id file. It is basically a list of numbers

```
1761
1762
1763
1764
1765
```

So my ultimate aim is to go in a loop where the first curl request will go --data-urlencode 'XXID=1761' second request will go --data-urlencode 'XXID=1762', third goes --data-urlencode 'XXID=1763' etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use single quotes `'` for variables as anything between them will be treated as literal text and not be expanded by the shell.
Instead use double quotes `"`.

Also `find` is an utility to search files, not **in** files.

The following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat ./id)
do
        curl -X POST 'https:/myurla \
        --header 'X-XX-Authorization: XX' \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
        --header 'ACS-Licensing-Ack: XXXX' \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX' \
        --data-urlencode XXID="$line"
done
```

If your `id` file only contains a number which is increasing by 1 every line, you could use a `seq` of `{..}` to create a sequence of numbers:

```
for num in {1761..1765}
do
        echo $num
done
```

```
for num in $(seq 1761 1765)
do
        echo $num
done
```

Comment: Actually i tried that combination as well. when i do that like you requested i get the below {"code":"400-bad-request","message":"XXID must be sent in the request body"}

Comment: You want the **content** of the file to be XXID or the name of the file?

Comment: I want the content of the file to be the value of xxid. The content of the file is 1741, 1742 etc. So it should loop as --data-urlencode "XXID=1741",  --data-urlencode "XXID=1742" etc

Comment: Well, that cant work like that. `find` is for finding files, not file contents. Please edit your question with example data from your `id` file.

Comment: ok i edited this question. i am new to programming so apologise for the confusion.

Comment: thank you so very much. so i didnt follow bin/bash route but i based the following solution based on your answer. for i in $(cat ./id);
do curl -X POST 'https:/XXXX' \
--header 'X-Splunkbase-Authorization: XXXu' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'ACS-Licensing-Ack: http://XXX' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
--data-urlencode splunkbaseID="$line"
done